# using top to identify cpu core number with qsub pbspro

Tags: top, parallelism, qsub

I have a shared memory server with PBSpro installed as the job manager.  There are 320 cores total, and pbs is configured so there is 1 job queue having 30 of the 32 cpu's so 300 physical cores to be divided up among users, with 2 cpu's or 20 cores left for head node operation.

some software will run on or parallelize over 100+ cores, and i'd like to verify N processes from user A are on unique and separate core numbers than the M processes from user B.

If I use `top` I can do

```
hit F to get into sort menu
hit J to sort by P = Last CPU used (SMP)
```

this gives me a P column in the top output having core number, but on a 300 core system I can only get around 70-80 rows before I run out of screen, on a 1920x1200 monitor.  I can start shrinking font size in the terminal window but in the end I won't be able to see up to 300 rows, not that I can even visually process all that with top updating every 1..3 seconds.

My goal is to quickly and easily

- verify users are running stuff in the job queue within the correct core numbers, and not on the head node
- verify for a given cpu core that is at 100%, or anything over 50%, that only one process from one user is running on it.  I want to make sure that if user A with programA.x is on core #234, user B with anything.x is NOT on core #234.

what's the best way to do this, when a single image shared memory server has many cores?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ps with the custom option and sort flags. I'm not 100% sure what sort of filtering you want from your question.

So, perhaps you mean show me all processes. I want to see the CPU they are on, the username and process name. Sort this by CPU

> ps ax -o c,user,comm k c

The "ax" means all processes, "-o c,user,comm" is what columns to display and "k c" means sort by CPU.